AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.layers' has no attribute 'TFSMLayer'
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.layers' has no attribute 'TFSMLayer'
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/exec_code.py", line 88, in exec_func_with_error_handling
result = func()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 579, in code_to_exec
exec(code, module.dict)
File "/home/user/app/app.py", line 10, in 
model = tf.keras.layers.TFSMLayer("./saved_model", call_endpoint="serving_default")

The issue might be due to incompatible versions of TensorFlow/Keras or by an incorrect import statement. To better diagnose the issue, please provide more details on the issue, including the versions of TensorFlow and Keras you're using and relevant code snippet, particularly where you're trying to use TFSMLayer. This will help us better understand and resolve the problem.
